# How do you ask someone's "international age" in Korean?

Tags: conversation

How do you ask someone's "international age" (starting from zero, incrementing on their birthday; as opposed to [Korean age](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_age_reckoning)) in Korean?

Answer (score 3):

I asked a Korean person, so answering my own question:

> 가: 만으로 몇 살이에요?
>
> 나: 만 ㅇㅇ살이에요.

Note, I was told this was rarely used, so could be a bit of an awkward question to ask.

Comment: It's quite frequently used actually.

Comment: @Memming I wouldn't say that frequent in general settings, but definitely not weird to ask at all

Answer (score -2):

**How to ask age regardless of calendar/time in womb:**

TO GENERALLY YOUR AGE PEOPLE:

본인은 나이가 어떻게 되시죠?

For the person I'm looking at (you), the age...What has it become (risen to)?

TO ESTEEMED OLDER PEOPLE

본인은 연세가 어떻게 되세요?

(The translation is the same, and the sentence ending a tad more polite, maybe, with the word for age given honor).

TO CHILDREN

너는 몇 살이야?

How many (years) old are you?

**How to handle the request while excluding time in womb and infering :**

There is a consideration for the fact that Koreans often use the lunar calendar and also count the time in the womb.

Asking age **만으로** will get you the solar calendar, more western age that is comparable to people from countries like mine, 미국.

My personal approach is to just get the age and follow-up with saying 만으로 어떻게 되세요? Often the listener will first respond with a qualifying question of whether or not we are to discuss this 만으로 or not making the need for the extra adverb less necessary.

Though it is not grammatically correct I have often heard adverbs added after the sentence to clarify the question, so this would be a much less awkward way to handle the question in one shot:

> 연세가 어떻게 되세요? 만으로...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I'm specifically asking about international age (time out of the womb), and none of these address this.

Comment: As I stated, the point of the awkward feeling in that question is that you need to lead with a non awkward question to establish that you were talking about age and then you can hone in on that awkward detail.

Comment: Anyway I answered the original question first before you edited it. After you added it I edited mine to address the change in your question. I see your edit occurred 7 hours ago, I don't know why my application only just showed it, perhaps it was not synced properly.

Comment: Fair enough, I did initially ask it in reverse and I guess the original question got cached somewhere. With your edit, it addresses it, but I can I suggest adding something at the beginning why you go into asking in general first as the question isn't really answered until the last line? I asked the question assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that people would know how to ask age in general.